# How add company-dabbrev to the Company completion popup?

Tags: company-mode, abbrev

### Setup:

GUI version GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
of 2015-07-25 on KAEL

[Compiled from EmacsW64.](http://emacsbinw64.sourceforge.net/)

, using the latest version of  from MELPA

Windows 7 x64 bit.

### Situation:

For example, I'm typing in the buffer foobarsentence.

And then start a new line below that, and typing fooba, I expected to get `foobarsentence` suggested from the Company popup completion window. But there is no `foobarsentence`.

I found it out from another answer that I could use company-dabbrev`` for that, bound, <kbd>M-/</kbd>. But I couldn't figure out how I could 'feed' the suggestions from `company-dabbrev` into the popup-window. I made a screencast gif to made my question clear.

[image]

As you can see, <kbd>M-/</kbd> calls `company-dabbrev`. But I would like to see that suggested in the company completion popup. It surprised me this is not by default.

Any suggestion in order to 'feed' the suggestions from `company-dabbrev` to company popup window?

Comment: What major-mode is this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here is how completion in company works (I am simplifying a bit; a more detailed description can be found in documentation of `company-backends` <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`company-backends`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

You have a list of backends (completion engines) which company should try to provide completion at point. Company tries each of these backends one after the another, and the first one that returns any candidates is used for completion; the rest of the backends are ignored. So by default, only one backend is used at a time.

In your case (you seem in emacs-lisp-mode), emacs-lisp backend is returning candidates for completion, so `company-dabbrev` is never used by company for completion; hence, you never get `foobarsentence` in completion. So, you might want to change company-backends so that `company-dabbrev` comes before `company-elisp` (or `company-capf` in recent emacsen). But I guess that is not what you want, since that would reverse the current situation and you will not get completions from emacs-lisp backend (in which case, read on).

Company provides a way to merge completions from multiple sources using what it calls `grouped` backends. Usually, the members of `company-backends` are individual backends, but it can also be a list of backends; in which case, the completion from the backends are merged provided they return same `prefix` or the text to be completed (please see documentation of `company-backends` for detailed description).

So, if you want to merge completions from `company-elisp` (on recent emacsen `company-capf` is used) and `company-dabbrev`, simply do this:

```
(add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-capf company-dabbrev))
```

Additionally, you can merge different backends using the `:with` keyword

```
(add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-capf :with company-dabbrev))
```

This is different from the previous example using a list of backends without `:with`, since company will use only the backends before `:with` for determining the `prefix` (the text to be completed). This implies that the candidates from backends after `:with` will be ignored by company, irrespective of whether the backends return a `prefix` or no, if none of the backends before `:with` return a `prefix`.

You might want to set this locally in emacs-lisp buffer (I prefer doing so).

Comment: @wasamasa thanks for the feedback, edited my answer to mention `:with`

Comment: Sir, you deserve my vote. I really enjoyed your explaination, and learned things about Company. Thanks for that.

Comment: Glad I could help