# Is there a way to make auto-complete aware of user defined variables

Tags: spacemacs, auto-complete-mode, scheme

I am using spacemacs with racket-mode, company-mode, and scheme-complete, to code in racket, and its pretty efficient.  But, in order to have completion for user defined variables and functions, I have to press tab to activate scheme-complete, since only scheme complete is aware of user defined variables/functions. And I don't know what Emacs thinks I want to type like I would if there was a drop down menu.  Is there any way to make company mode aware of the user-defined variables/functions that scheme complete is aware of, so that they appear in the drop down menu.  Currently it is only aware of built in functions like define, list, etc.  I am still relatively new to emacs/spacemacs so I might be doing something stupid.  Thanks in advance.

Edit: It seems like symbols become available after

```
racket run
```

is executed, but that doesn't exactly solve the problem of convenience.

Comment: Have you tried `geiser` instead?

Answer (score 4):

One of the most robust ways to get autocompletion is to use dabbrev. It's bound to M-/ by default. You can use it to autocomplete variables, functions and many other things.

Comment: refer: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15246/how-add-company-dabbrev-to-the-company-completion-popup

Comment: @npostavs The solution in the link doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Comment: I think they changed the names of some of the variables, I was able to activate it by customizing the variable company-backends.