# Company not active in shell/SQL, but it's says otherwise

Tags: company-mode

I use `company-dabbrev` as backend (source: [How add company-dabbrev to the Company completion popup?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15246/how-add-company-dabbrev-to-the-company-completion-popup)).

When I open `sql-mysql`, after filling my credentials, I type `show databases;` one of the databases is `information_schema` displayed in the buffer.

When I type `informatio` in the buffer, there is no completion from Company. When I do <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `company-backends`, I see the following:

```
(company-wsd-mode
(company-edbi :with company-yasnippet)
(company-bbdb :with company-yasnippet)
(company-nxml :with company-yasnippet)
(company-css :with company-yasnippet)
(company-eclim :with company-yasnippet)
(company-semantic :with company-yasnippet)
(company-clang :with company-yasnippet)
(company-xcode :with company-yasnippet)
(company-cmake :with company-yasnippet)
(company-capf :with company-yasnippet)
(company-files :with company-yasnippet)
(company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords :with company-yasnippet)
(company-oddmuse :with company-yasnippet)
(company-dabbrev :with company-yasnippet)
(company-yasnippet :with company-yasnippet)
(company-etags :with company-yasnippet)
(company-gtags :with company-yasnippet)
(company-sql :with company-yasnippet))
```

So `Company-dabbrev` is listed in the output. But why is there no completion for `information-schema` in SQL interactive mode buffer, while  `company-mode` is active as minor mode in same buffer and `company-dabbrev` is listed as backend?

Comment: Just a guess: maybe something else is using the same keybindig? Those used for completion are heavily contested ones.

Comment: Try `M-x company-diag`.